# Question about a plot.

Tags: fiction

So guys. I have a great idea for a book. And have been working on it for quite some time. The plot is kind of surrounding some government conspiracy theories in a more futuristic way. Basically a group of people came together in the early 1940s and the group has been passed down to some of the original founders children. It'll tell the story of how the group investigated each "conspiracy theory" at the time it occurred  and showing how it was planned by the government for control and or fear. It's hard to explain really, im sorry if I come across as confusing to some. But. After I finish it, do you think it's too radical to try to publish? Given its plot?

Comment: Hi Daniel! I'm sorry, but Writers.SE doesn't provide feedback or critique on story ideas (nor are we a good place for informal "market research" :P ). We're a Q&A site, addressing practical difficulties that crop up during writing (and publishing, etc.). More broadly speaking, there's really no way for an internet community to judge your idea - it's all in the execution! If you have specific difficulties where you feel something isn't working, or is preventing your book from being publishable - we'll be happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Plenty of novels revolving around government conspiracies have been published already, just look at [The girl who kicked the hornet nest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Girl_Who_Kicked_the_Hornets%27_Nest) and [Soylent Green](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soylent_Green) (those are the first examples I could think about).

Your novel won't be seen as a radical, because *it's fiction*. If you wanted to write a non-fiction book presenting conspiracy theories as true, you could maybe have trouble finding a publisher, and even in this case it wouldn't be impossible.

My advice would be to not worry too much about people misinterpreting your story, and focus on writing it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I think its fine. Almost any idea is viable in fiction because well, its fiction. Don't worry at this point on people not understanding it well, because people will probably understand it if you explain it properly throughout the novel.

That brings me to this point. You said you could not explain it well. I think that before you begin it, you should make sure you 100% understand your idea and are able to make a synopsis, in which you can explain it without difficulty.

Good luck!